# Best way to convert json to a python dict without the json library

Tags: python, json, dictionary, python-2.5

The json library does not work on my computer, so does anyone know the best way to convert json to a python dictionary? It needs to be python 2.5 compatible and not use any special libraries (libraries that don't come with 2.5).

Comment: Re-implement a JSON parser: http://json.org/

Comment: Use `simplejson`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791561/which-json-module-can-i-use-in-python-2-5

Comment: @AetherUnbound no special libraries. I specifically said that in the question. I have some sort of a solution. eval() although dangerous, works for what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at these ones:

- [Which JSON module can I use in Python 2.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791561/which-json-module-can-i-use-in-python-2-5)
- [Python 2.5 json without installing simplejson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846301/python-2-5-json-without-installing-simplejson)
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/2.5.2

Comment: Answers that provide link are bad in SO, these can be used to complement the answers, but not as base of them. These links are broken making your answer unusable.

Comment: This kind of thing you can post it as a comment, but it is not an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi @eyllanesc, yes, I know, you're right, and I take your point. The thing was that yesterday, when I wrote this, I had less than 50 points hence I wasn't able to comment on the original answer.